# How do I loop over all class properties defined using class-validator?

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I have a class defined using the class-validator package.

```
class Shape {
    @IsString()
    value?: string

    @IsString()
    id?: string
}
```

I'm looking for a way to access the properties and types defined in this class, is it possible?

I opened up class-validator and tried to tinker around with some of the internal code.

```
const metadataStorage = getMetadataStorage()
const targetMetadatas = metadataStorage
    .getTargetValidationMetadatas(Shape, undefined, false, false, undefined)

targetMetadatas.forEach(p => console.log(p))
```

Would log each property like this, however there's no type information here.

```
ValidationMetadata {
  groups: [],
  each: false,
  context: undefined,
  type: 'customValidation',
  target: [class Shape],
  propertyName: 'id',
  constraints: undefined,
  constraintCls: [class CustomConstraint],
  validationTypeOptions: undefined
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a function that returns all the decorators names, it's not 100% the type, but it is pretty usefull.

```
// eslint-disable-next-line
function propertyTypes (targetConstructor: Function) {
    const metadataStorage = getMetadataStorage()
    const targetMetadatas = metadataStorage
        .getTargetValidationMetadatas(targetConstructor, undefined, false, false, undefined)
    const groupedMetadatas = metadataStorage.groupByPropertyName(targetMetadatas);
    return Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(groupedMetadatas).map(([property, decorators]) => {
        const CM = decorators.map(decorator => metadataStorage.getTargetValidatorConstraints(decorator.constraintCls).map(v => v.name))
        return [property, CM.flat()]
    }))
}

console.log(propertyTypes(Shape))
// { value: [ 'isString' ], id: [ 'isString' ] }
```